# What's the phase change after permutated the position of these $1/2$ spin?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, fermions

We know that particle with $1/2$ spin is the fermion. If one exchange 2 identical particles' positions, they generate a total phase factor $e^{i\pi}=-1$.

One can proof these by rotation. If 2 spin-$1/2$ identical particles (spin-up) are placed on a circle ($\varphi=0,\pi$), and we rotate this circle by $\pi$ angle, i.e., we exchange their positions. We can find the phase factor by $SU(2)$ group:
$$
|\uparrow\rangle
\to e^{i\pi S_z} |\uparrow\rangle
=e^{i\pi/2} |\uparrow\rangle
$$
then total phase factor is $e^{i\pi/2}e^{i\pi/2}=e^{i\pi}=-1$.

Q.E.D.

---

However, if one considers 3 spin-$1/2$ identical particles(spin-up), rather than 2, and places them on a circle ($\varphi=0,2\pi/3,4\pi/3$). By rotating the circle by $2\pi/3$, one finds the total phase factor is $e^{i\pi/3}e^{i\pi/3}e^{i\pi/3}=e^{i\pi}=-1$.

[image]

That's not ok, because for 3 identical fermions, $|abc\rangle\to|bca\rangle\to|cab\rangle$ do not generate any non-trivial phase !!

---

So please show me where the mistake is.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your argument is that a permutation is NOT, in general, a rotation.  Hence your argument about "rotations" to interchange two spins does not carry to three spins.

I'm not quite sure how it is possible to implement your method for three spins: it is not possible with your setup to just interchange two of the three spins for instance.

Comment: I have updated a diagram for your reference.

Comment: @bacon  My point is: because your pebbles are rigidly attached to the ring, there is no rotation of the ring that can interchange green and red, i.e. you method cannot generate simple transpositions, i.e. it is not possible to map toations of the circle (there are only 3 different ones) to elements of the permutation group of 3 elements since this group contains 6 elements.

Comment: I get your point, the rotation group is not exactly the subgroup of the permutation group. In fact, I suspect both proofs (2 spinors and 3 spinors) are wrong.

Comment: @bacon yes that's a good way to summarize things,  I was also surprised about your two-spin example as I too suspect it is more an analogy than a rigorous approach.